# Data Transformation Pipeline Issue on Flight Fare Prediction End-to-End Machine Learning Project

Tags: machine-learning, pipelines

I am following the process shown on [Wine Quality Prediction End-to-End ML Project](https://youtu.be/pxk1Fr33-L4?si=zqJ_Ice6YT8pLYzJ) on Krish Naik's YouTube channel to do a Flight Fare Prediction Project.

I am facing an issue with Data Transformation Pipeline.

I run this cell of data transformation pipeline on [03_data_transformation.ipynb](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb):
[image]

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    data_transformation_config = config.get_data_transformation_config()
    data_transformation = DataTransformation(config=data_transformation_config)
    # data_transformation.train_test_spliting()
    # New Line
    data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

[image]

I have been stuck here for days. But can't fix the issue.

In the data transformation process, I am not getting any error.

I am getting error in only the code of data transformation pipeline.

Would you please help me to fix this issue?